# How is generic function implemented in java?

Tags: java, generics, covariance

As per my understanding the following generic function in java:

```
public static <T> T f(T x) {
   Integer[] arr = new Integer[4];
   T ret = (T) arr[2];
   return ret;
}
```

is compiled to the following form (as it is unbounded):

```
public static Object f(Object x) {
   Integer[] arr = new Integer[4];
   Object ret = (Object) arr[2];
   return ret;
}
```

However, when I run the following statement, the compiler is able to figure out the return value to be Integer type. How does the compiler figure it out?

```
Integer i = f(new Integer(4));
```

Shouldn't the function be written as following for the above statement to work?

```
  public static <T extends Integer> T f(T x) {
       Integer[] arr = new Integer[4];
       T ret = (T) arr[2];
       return ret;
    }
```

Comment: You could have chosen a nicer example :)

Comment: Actually my question really is how does the compiler figure out the correct return type for generic functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generics use type erasure. That basically means that generics are nothing more than implicit casts so when you do:

```
List<Integer> ...
```

it's no different to a normal `List` and may contain `Integer`s or anything really. You're just telling Java to cast `get()` to an `Integer` (and other things). The type simply isn't retained at runtime (mostly).

Arrays are different. Arrays are what's called *covariant*. That means their type is retained at runtime. So you can do:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2 = (List<String>)list1;
list2.add("hello");
```

which is perfectly legal and will compile and run. But:

```
Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[10];
String[] arr2 = (String[])arr1; // compiler error
```

But it gets more subtle than that too.

```
Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[10];
Object[] arr2 = (Object[])arr1;
arr2[5] = "hello"; // runtime error!
```

As to your function. When you write:

```
public static <T> T f(T x) {
  Integer[] arr = new Integer[4];
  T ret = (T) arr[2];
  return ret;
}
```

you're telling the compiler to derive `T`, being the argument type and the return type, from the argument. So when you pass in an `Integer` the return type is `Integer`. When you call:

```
Integer i = f(new Integer(4));
```

the compiler is simply following your instructions. The function does take and return an `Object` in compiled form but it just does this:

```
Integer i = (Integer)f(new Integer(4));
```

implicitly.

Just like the `List` example above there is nothing stopping you have `f()` return anything you like rather than what it's supposed to return based on the parameterized type.

Comment: I don't think 'covariant' means that their types are retained at runtime... don't covariant and contravariant have something to do with inheritance and if a subclass can take the place of a superclass?

Comment: @Pablo: see http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/java/java-theory-generic-050323/page2.html

Comment: funny. In the first paragraph of that blogpost says: "Arrays in the Java language are covariant -- which means that if `Integer` extends `Number` (which it does), then not only is an `Integer` also a `Number`, but an `Interger[]` is also a `Number[]`"

Comment: Pablo Fernandez is correct, covariance has nothing to do with whether a type is retained at runtime.  The word you are looking for is "reified".

Answer (score 6):

Somebody with more knowledge in this topic might jump in later, meanwhile my humble explanation is this:

What you say is right, generics have **type erasure** which means that generic information is not available at runtime. *It is* however available at *compile* time and that's how the compiler can figure out that you're mixing types.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the compiler figures that the return type is the same type as the parameter passed to the function, since they're both parameterized to type T, which is resolved to be `Integer`. When generating the bytecode, it then [erases](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the type parameters information.

Comment: Thats interesting. But wouldn't the JVM complain at runtime since the object returned is of type Object?

Comment: Why would it complain about that? An Integer *is* an Object, they're both internally implemented as a pointer to a chunk of memory. It's basically the same as casting it, except the JVM doesn't bother type-checking because it knows the cast is safe.